# how to use dart-mode and d-mode together (why can't we all get along?)

Tags: emacs, elisp, dart

I am trying to use dart-mode and d-mode in emacs 24. If I use either mode alone everything is fine. If I use both modes on each type of file respectively I get errors when trying to indent the D code.

Below is the error when, after the following have been required at init,:

```
(require 'd-mode)
(require 'dart-mode)
```

I then turn on d-mode on the first loaded D file.

```
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 1) signaled (invalid-function (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (funcall ad--addoit-function))))
```

Again - if I don't *require 'dart-mode* everything works fine.

The d-mode is from https://raw.github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode/master/d-mode.el and the dart mode is from https://github.com/nex3/dart-mode/blob/master/dart-mode.el

Does this mean there is some incompatibility between the two modes, or some other setup issue? I have tried with --no-site-file but still no luck.

---

Said another way, given the following, if I bring up a D file and *M-x d-mode* in it, I get the issue:

```
user@user-thinkpad:/tmp/breakEmacs$ ls
dart-mode.el  d-mode.el  emacs_test.el
user@user-thinkpad:/tmp/breakEmacs$ cat emacs_test.el
(add-to-list 'load-path "/tmp/breakEmacs")
(require 'd-mode)
(require 'dart-mode)
user@user-thinkpad:/tmp/breakEmacs$ emacs-snapshot --no-init-file --no-site-file -l /tmp/breakEmacs/emacs_test.el
```

I hope this way successfully removes potential issues with any of my .emacs stuff?

---

Per @wvxvw's suggestion, I tried to debug by adding *(setq debug-on-error t)* which provided a callstack like below. I say *like* because some lines were large and looked like binary encoded, so I elided some text. But, hopefully something here is useful to point to the culprit?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (funcall ad--addoit-function))))
  (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (funcall ad--addoit-function)))()
  ad-Advice-c-parse-state(#[nil ...] 5])
  apply(ad-Advice-c-parse-state #[nil ...] nil)
  c-parse-state()
  #[nil  ...] 8 ("/usr/share/emacs/24.3.50/lisp/progmodes/cc-engine.elc" . 156151)]()
  ad-Advice-c-guess-basic-syntax(#[nil ...] 8 ("/usr/share/emacs/24.3.50/lisp/progmodes/cc-engine.elc" . 156151)])
  apply(ad-Advice-c-guess-basic-syntax #[nil ...] 8 ("/usr/share/emacs/24.3.50/lisp/progmodes/cc-engine.elc" . 156151)] nil)
  c-guess-basic-syntax()
  c-indent-line()
  c-indent-command(nil)
  c-indent-line-or-region(nil nil)
  call-interactively(c-indent-line-or-region nil nil)
  command-execute(c-indent-line-or-region)
```

Comment: Huh, using Emacs 24.2.1 and those exact same implementations of d-mode and dart-mode, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Cool. Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot? Any information that would be helpful?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure.  I added the [tag:elisp] tag, since it seems like one way or another it's a bug in elisp code.

Comment: @DarshanComputing: I added a very simple way to see it. I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1. Did you actually open a d file and enter d-mode?

Comment: @user1338952 Yeah, I opened a D file, entered d-mode, added and removed code, and had emacs successfully indent my code through various means.

Comment: @wvxvw I tried --debug-init with --no-splash where I do a find-file of a d file - so the error happens at init. But there is no "break" into anything, just the same error message above jit_lock_function in the *Warnings* buffer. Also between the 2, d and dart, dart has _ad-do-it_ and _ad-return-value_, but I don't know enough emacs lisp to know what the issue is.

Comment: @wvxvw - Thanks for the advice. I found the offending defadvice, and while I don't really understand what is up, I made these changes and it now works. This is a terrible approach - but it will keep me going if/until really fixed.


    <   (if (not (or (c-major-mode-is 'dart-mode) (c-major-mode-is 'd-mode))) (ad-do-it)
    ---
    >   (if (not (c-major-mode-is 'dart-mode)) (ad-do-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in dart-mode.  It uses code like:

```
(if (not (c-major-mode-is 'dart-mode))
    (ad-do-it)
```

whereas it should be

```
(if (not (c-major-mode-is 'dart-mode))
    ad-do-it
```

Note the removal of parentheses around `ad-do-it`.